# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am getting this error while migrating local laravel code to server.
This issue is still unanswered on stackoverflow.
I have run the commands :

```
composer update -vv
composer install
chmod -r 777 storage/
chmod -r 777 app/storage
```

The issue in detail is here:

```
Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, string given, called in /home/33128-24818.cloudwaysapps.com/asmmvdanac/public_html/bootstrap/app.php on line 16 and defined in /home/33128-24818.cloudwaysapps.com/asmmvdanac/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php on line 109
Stack trace:
  1. {main}() /home/33128-24818.cloudwaysapps.com/asmmvdanac/public_html/public/index.php:0
  2. require_once() /home/33128-24818.cloudwaysapps.com/asmmvdanac/public_html/public/index.php:35
  3. Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->__construct() /home/33128-24818.cloudwaysapps.com/asmmvdanac/public_html/bootstrap/app.php:16
```

The app.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Create The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The first thing we will do is create a new Laravel application instance
| which serves as the "glue" for all the components of Laravel, and is
| the IoC container for the system binding all of the various parts.
|
*/

$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Bind Important Interfaces
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, we need to bind some important interfaces into the container so
| we will be able to resolve them when needed. The kernels serve the
| incoming requests to this application from both the web and CLI.
|
*/

$app->singleton(
    'Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel',
    'App\Http\Kernel'
);

$app->singleton(
    'Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel',
    'App\Console\Kernel'
);

$app->singleton(
    'Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler',
    'App\Exceptions\Handler'
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Return The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This script returns the application instance. The instance is given to
| the calling script so we can separate the building of the instances
| from the actual running of the application and sending responses.
|
*/

return $app;
```

Comment: So somewhere in your bootstrap/app.php file there is a problem, but we need to see the code in order to be able to give much more help than that. Does it work locally? Are you running the same versions of everything on the server? What have you tried to debug it?

Comment: @Spudley I think there is a difference in versions locally and on server, and I don't know why. This is an existing project, on local machine there is no app.php but on server it is. The only debugging I did was to check the logs and search online, I am new to laravel.

Comment: @viv This is why you shouldn't run composer update. You just need the `composer.lock` file from local, drop it to the server and only run `composer install`

Comment: @Avalanche : ok I just did what people suggested online, I will try this out.